# AVAudioPlayer crashing after upgrading to iOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, avaudioplayer, exc-bad-access

I was successfully using the AVAudioPlayer class, but after upgrading to iOS 5.0 my iPad app crashes when trying to listen to what I've previously recorded. Under iOS 4.3 all is well.

Here is the code:

```
   NSError * error = NULL;
   player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: 
                             [NSURL fileURLWithPath:destinationString] 
                             error:&error]; 

   if(player == NULL)
    NSLog( @"error in creating AVAudioPlayer - %@ %@", [error domain], [error localizedDescription] );

         [player prepareToPlay];
         player.delegate = self;
         [player play]; 

- (NSString*) documentsPath
{
    NSArray *searchPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* _documentsPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];  
    return _documentsPath;
}

-(void) initRecord
{
    audioSession = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] retain];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

    destinationString = [[self documentsPath]
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myRecording.caf"];
    NSLog(@"%@", destinationString);
    NSURL *destinationURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: destinationString];

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                              nil];
    NSError *error;
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:destinationURL settings:settings error:&error];
    recorder.delegate = self;
}
```

The app crashes at this line:

```
 player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: 
                             [NSURLfileURLWithPath:destinationString] 
                             error:NULL];
```

I've already tried NSZombieEnabled that gives me:

```
0x5368b0 <myRecording = 005BD7D0 | Tag = -1>
*** -[NSPathStore2 length]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5290e0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change those initial lines to:

```
-(void) playRecording
{
    AVAudioPlayer * player = NULL;

    if(destinationString && ([destinationString length] > 15)
    {
        NSError * error = NULL;
        player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: 
                             [NSURL fileURLWithPath:destinationString] 
                             error:&error]; 

        if(player == NULL)
        {
            NSLog( @"error in creating AVAudioPlayer - %@ %@", [error domain], [error localizedDescription] );
        } else {
            [player prepareToPlay];
            player.delegate = self;
            [player play]; 
            // F.Y.I. -- this player NEEDS to be released when it is done playing
            // 
            // right now you appear to be leaking memory from both AVAudioPlayer and AVAudioRecorder
        }
    } else {
        NSLog( @"destination string doesn't exist or is invalid");
    }
}
```

I also gave you some error checking code too.

Comment: I'll test it and let you know the results. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Hi Michael. Now I got these two errors: error in creating AVAudioPlayer - (null) (null) & -[NSPathStore2 length]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x59b9340. I don't know why but after upgrading to iOS 5  there is this error in creating the AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Could you update your original question with the new code and let me (or anyone else) see what's going on in context?

Comment: Sure, I just did it and have also shared the initRecord method.

Comment: And I've updated my code as well. I have a strong feeling your autoreleased "destinationString" is null.

Comment: And this is also strange, because I'm being able to record an audio file, using the "destinationString". Just when I'm going to access it to play, the app crashes. I can't understand why it is returning null.

Comment: What is returning null?  The Player or the destinationString?  If it's the latter, retain it after creating it and release it after creating the AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Hey, Michael! That worked! I've used  [destinationString retain]; Because previously I tried [_documentsPath retain]; with no avail. Thanks a lot for your help!!!